# How to make this run only once?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get it where If someone clicks the button it will update the database but what happens if I enter 50 then it will keep running it and I have a tracking board that sums everything up so it overloads my server and makes the total in the 1000's when its normally just over 100.

I've tried a document ready function, I've had on and one. ('click') and it keeps running multiple times

```
$('#update_new_used-counter').one('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();

       let updated_new_counter = $('#new_sold-update').val().trim();
       let updated_used_counter = $('#used_sold-update').val().trim();

    trackingBoardRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {

        let current_new_counter = snapshot.val().new;
        let current_used_counter = snapshot.val().used;

        if (updated_new_counter == '') {
            trackingBoardRef.update({
                new: current_new_counter,
            });
        } else {
            trackingBoardRef.update({
                new: updated_new_counter,
            })
        };


        if (updated_used_counter == '') {
            trackingBoardRef.update({
                used: current_used_counter,
            });
        } else {
            trackingBoardRef.update({
                used: updated_used_counter,
            })
        };

        console.log(snapshot.val().new);
        console.log(snapshot.val().used);
    });
});
```

That's what I have now and it just keeps running multiple times until firebase says I had to many requests and stops it. I just want it to update once

Comment: What is `trackingBoardRef`?  What is the "value" event you are passing to `on`?  Are you mixing jQuery with React?

Comment: @jmargolisvt No, There is no react. TrackingBoardRef is a ref to Firebase

Comment: ```var trackingBoardRef = database.ref('tracking_board');```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call:

```
trackingBoardRef.on("value", function(snapshot) {
```

You attach a listener to the data in `trackingBoardRef` that will be triggered right away with the current value, and then subsequently whenever the data under `trackingBoardRef` changes. And since you're changing data under `trackingBoardRef` in your code, you're creating an infinite loop.

If you only want to read the data once, you can use the aptly named `once` method:

```
trackingBoardRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
  ...
```

---

Note that if you're update the value under `trackingBoardRef` based on its current value, you really should [use a transaction](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#save_data_as_transactions) to prevent users overwriting each other's changes.